# Fingerprint Recognition on screen IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, fingerprint

> **Note:** I need an answer in swift 3, not swift 4 or swift 2.

Is it possible to unlock my app with fingerprint only using the screen and not the home button. This is for iphones which are under the 6th generation. I plan on having the user put their finger on the screen and not on the home button to unlock the app. How can I do this? If it isn't possible, is there an alternative for letting users sign in who are on iphone 5 and ios 10?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Depends. If you're looking for the touch to recognize a specific user, no, but if you want them to tap the screen to unlock it, you just switch to another view on touch? edit: TouchID is a specific piece of tech that was added to the home button. Unfortunately, there isn't a way with software to emulate that.

Comment: There is no fingerprint sensors under the screen of iPhones... you could detect a touch, but that is different than fingerprint recognition...

Comment: So it is impossible?

Comment: Correct - iPhone screens cannot read fingerprints

Comment: Thank You, can you add this as an answer

Comment: Unfortunately, yeah. Rumor has it that's more or less why FaceID was being looked at as the thing for iPhone X because they couldn't quite get the fingerprint sensor in display ready before launch.

Comment: Read yesterday that a company called Vivo is about to be the first one to market with that technology.

Comment: If you only want to authenticate the local user, then use the local authentication framework; it will fallback to device passcode if biometrics aren't available.  You need to cater for this situation anyway for biometric capable devices where the user has not enrolled biometrics or biometric authentication failed.  If you need to authenticate different users on the same device then you can't use biometrics on any device since it doesn't differentiate between enrolled biometric data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible - iPhone screens cannot read fingerprints like the home button can.

Comment: Are there any alternatives for letting the user login without having a backend?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible if you want stored users

Comment: you could possibly implement a low quality facial recognition but even that would require some kind of backend to match users to faces. That backend could be some kind of local database though if you're not worried about syncing to a backend on a server (ie create credentials for the user, store them locally, they unlock with those).

Comment: Low quality facial recognition might not be secure, so I won't try it

Comment: then you're out of luck. Perhaps implement TouchID for the users that have it but leveraging user/pass for others

Comment: `Are there any alternatives for letting the user login without having a backend?` You can store user names and passwords in the keychain and corresponding user preferences in UserDefaults. When a user tries to login, match the user name and password against stored ones, thereby "recognizing" a user.